# Get records for past month, day and a specific 24 hour period in the past

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

At the moment I have:

```
SELECT timeslot_start_time
    , name
    , description
    , etc
FROM Table1
WHERE Timeslot_start_time >= '2022-02-01' 
ORDER BY Timeslot_start_time
```

Q1. Instead of doing this manually, is there a way the table only gets data that is a month old from today automatically?

Q2. Additionally, my data is in this format: 22-02-15 21:45:00, with data reading every 15 minutes. Is there a way I can create a column(/table or whatever is best) that filters only the last 24hours automatically?

Q3. Additionally, is it possible to filter the last 24hrs but from a specific time. For example filtering the last 24hrs up to 10pm, So 10pm-10pm.

I hope all of that makes sense

Comment: Column Timeslot_start_time data type?

Comment: The answer to just about all of your questions is "use views". (Except Q3, that one might be "use a table-valued function".)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @jarlh Sorry Im very new, what data type? The timeslot_start_time is in date/time format, taken every 15 minutes

Comment: `in date/time format` - so, is the column `datetime` or is it a string type?

Comment: @AaronBertrand date/time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data could be queried using basic date arithmetic:

> gets data that is a month old from today automatically?

"A month" is ambiguous (like past 30 days, all dates in previous month, etc). But most simple definition is to use dateadd and let SQL Server decide:

```
WHERE timeslot_start_time >= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

> that filters only the last 24hours automatically?

```
WHERE timeslot_start_time >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

> is it possible to filter the last 24hrs but from a specific time. For
> example filtering the last 24hrs up to 10pm, So 10pm-10pm.

```
DECLARE @d2 DATETIME = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(
    DATEPART(YEAR, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
    DATEPART(MONTH, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
    DATEPART(DAY, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
    22,
    0,
    0,
    0
);
IF @d2 > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    -- if 10pm today is in the future then use yesterday
    SET @d2 = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @d2);

SELECT ...
WHERE timeslot_start_time >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, @d2)
AND   timeslot_start_time <  @d2
```

Comment: You could also use SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS and knock off the extra two zeroes. :-)

Comment: Thank you @/SalmanA @AaronBertrand. For Q3, I wrote the same script for a 7 day period, but now it seems to be overwriting. Would I have to write separate scripts instead of having them in a single sql to overcome this?

Comment: You can post another question.